# Registration Hooks don't appear to be working

Tags: functions, hooks, login, user-registration

I am trying to hook in to automatically sign-in the user after registration. (using a GravityForms registration form).

None of the hooks seem to be working.  I've tried: gform_user_registered, user_register, a filtered 'update_user_metadata'....

Why would this not kill the script after a registration happens?

```
add_action("user_register", "my_auto_login");
function my_auto_login($user_id) {
    die('x');
}
```

Login after registration seems like it should not be that complicated.

Comment: Isn't there a support forum at the gravity forms site? It's a commercial plugin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Gravity forms gform_user_registered hook.  It fires after the registration and will return the $user_id.

```
function my_auto_login( $user_id ) {
wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, false, is_ssl() );
wp_redirect( admin_url( 'profile.php' ) );
exit;
}

add_action( 'gform_user_registered', 'my_auto_login' );
```

Comment: Perhaps the order of the action and function matter?  It seems that they are reversed in a lot of examples.  Either way, I've never seen wp_set_auth_cookie() used like that to make this work.  Thanks A TON Chris !

Comment: @J_B I guess it worked pretty cool. There is also `wp_set_current_user($user_id);` but I guess it's not needed here.

Comment: yes, it did work.  One attempt of mine was using `wp_set_current_user` along with a set cookie function.. but your suggestion was the only one that seemed to do anything.  I would still like to know why putting `die()` had no effect.. Thanks again.

Comment: This will no longer work: `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /...activate.php:35)`